# iOS7 web app breaks home button

Tags: ios

I'm having a very perculiar problem. I did not test this on other iPhones, but after using my web app (added on the homescreen) for some time (about 5-10 min), my home button stops working and stubbornly refuses to take me to the home screen. The web app still works normal and I can still start Siri (long press on the home button) but when I give it a voice command to open Safari, it says it cannot. There is no other solution but to manually restart the device.

I have no idea what parts of code to share, and short of copy pasting the entire app, I will list some of the important features I can think of, but please do ask if there is anthing else you want to know. I have disabled the app cache manifest and am using jQuery, Tappable (library for touch events) and History (cross-browser push states) javascript libraries. I am also making use of a lot of Ajax requests. I'm using the following meta tags `<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes'>` `<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black'>`. This never happens when I open it in Safari.

Did anyone else encounter this sort of a problem and what would be some obvious culprits?